# User permission on views

Tags: list-view

In my document library there are some documents. Along with the default "All Documents" view I created one more view called as "Personalized View", which is filtered on user login's, so whenever a user logs in, he get to see only the documents which he created i.e., "personalized view". At the same time when a user like manager logs in he get to see the "All Documents" view. How could I achieve this..

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? You could do audience targeting on webparts to achieve this in MOSS or SharePoint Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can control permissions on views and/or columns with [this addon](http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/) from codeplex.  I have put it to use in my production portal, and it works like a charm!

If you want to remove a view completely (such as the "Merge Documents" view in a document library), create a user for "nobody" and put that in the "include" boxes in the view-permissions.